# what attributes are more efficient for a Point class?

Tags: c++, performance, opengl

Ok, I want to create the class Point3f, which is a class of points consist in 3D float coordinates.

So, I have two trivial ways to define the attributes of the class:

```
class Point3f
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

or

```
class Point3f
{
    float coord[3];
}
```

I want to know which is more (generally) efficient, especially for a graphics program. I.E. which is better for drawing the point: glVertex3f() or glVertex3v()?
I don't know if I'm right. I think the first need more run-time memory and  the other need more cpu usage.

Edit: And what about if we are talking about more complex types like a triangle consist in 3 points or a tetrahedron consist in 3 triangles -> Attributes: Array or one by one?

Please, tell me which is more efficient and why!

Comment: The usual approach for a vector class is to use a union between an array of real (floating-point) scalars and an anonymous structure. Something like: `class Point3f { union { struct { float x, y, z; }; float v[3]; }};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the assembly generated for basic functions (I used GCC 4.8.1 on OS X 10.7.4)

```
struct Point3D {
  float m_data[3];
};

struct Point3Ds {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
};

double dot(const Point3D& p1, const Point3D& p2) {
  asm("# Dot - Point3D");
  return p1.m_data[0] * p2.m_data[0] +
         p1.m_data[1] * p2.m_data[1] +
         p1.m_data[2] * p2.m_data[2];
}

double dot(const Point3Ds& p1, const Point3Ds&p2) {
  asm("# Dot - Point3Ds");  
  return p1.x * p2.x +
         p1.y * p2.y +
         p1.z * p2.z;
}

Point3D cross(const Point3D& p1, const Point3D& p2) {
  asm("# Cross - Point3D");  
  return { p1.m_data[1] * p2.m_data[2] - p1.m_data[2] * p2.m_data[1],
           p1.m_data[2] * p2.m_data[0] - p1.m_data[0] * p2.m_data[2],
           p1.m_data[0] * p2.m_data[1] - p1.m_data[1] * p2.m_data[0]};
}

Point3D cross(const Point3Ds& p1, const Point3Ds& p2) {
  asm("# Cross - Point3Ds");  
  return { p1.y * p2.z - p1.z * p2.y,
           p1.z * p2.x - p1.x * p2.z,
           p1.x * p2.y - p1.y * p2.x};
}
```

Compiling as `g++ -O3 -S` I obtain the following assembler (relevant parts):

```
# 12 "point3f.cpp" 1
    # Dot - Point3D
# 0 "" 2
    movss   (%rdi), %xmm0
    movss   4(%rdi), %xmm1
    mulss   (%rsi), %xmm0
    mulss   4(%rsi), %xmm1
    addss   %xmm1, %xmm0
    movss   8(%rdi), %xmm1
    mulss   8(%rsi), %xmm1
    addss   %xmm1, %xmm0
    unpcklps    %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvtps2pd    %xmm0, %xmm0
    ret
LFE0:
    .align 4,0x90
    .globl __Z3dotRK8Point3DsS1_
__Z3dotRK8Point3DsS1_:
LFB1:
# 19 "point3f.cpp" 1
    # Dot - Point3Ds
# 0 "" 2
    movss   (%rdi), %xmm0
    movss   4(%rdi), %xmm1
    mulss   (%rsi), %xmm0
    mulss   4(%rsi), %xmm1
    addss   %xmm1, %xmm0
    movss   8(%rdi), %xmm1
    mulss   8(%rsi), %xmm1
    addss   %xmm1, %xmm0
    unpcklps    %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvtps2pd    %xmm0, %xmm0
    ret
LFE1:
    .align 4,0x90
    .globl __Z5crossRK7Point3DS1_
__Z5crossRK7Point3DS1_:
LFB2:
# 26 "point3f.cpp" 1
    # Cross - Point3D
# 0 "" 2
    movss   4(%rdi), %xmm3
    movss   8(%rdi), %xmm1
    movss   8(%rsi), %xmm5
    movaps  %xmm3, %xmm2
    movss   4(%rsi), %xmm4
    movaps  %xmm1, %xmm0
    mulss   %xmm5, %xmm2
    mulss   %xmm4, %xmm0
    subss   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movss   (%rdi), %xmm0
    mulss   %xmm0, %xmm5
    movss   %xmm2, -24(%rsp)
    movss   (%rsi), %xmm2
    mulss   %xmm4, %xmm0
    mulss   %xmm2, %xmm1
    mulss   %xmm3, %xmm2
    subss   %xmm5, %xmm1
    subss   %xmm2, %xmm0
    movss   %xmm1, -20(%rsp)
    movss   %xmm0, -16(%rsp)
    movq    -24(%rsp), %xmm0
    movd    -16(%rsp), %xmm1
    ret
LFE2:
    .align 4,0x90
    .globl __Z5crossRK8Point3DsS1_
__Z5crossRK8Point3DsS1_:
LFB3:
# 33 "point3f.cpp" 1
    # Cross - Point3Ds
# 0 "" 2
    movss   4(%rdi), %xmm3
    movss   8(%rdi), %xmm1
    movss   8(%rsi), %xmm5
    movaps  %xmm3, %xmm2
    movss   4(%rsi), %xmm4
    movaps  %xmm1, %xmm0
    mulss   %xmm5, %xmm2
    mulss   %xmm4, %xmm0
    subss   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movss   (%rdi), %xmm0
    mulss   %xmm0, %xmm5
    movss   %xmm2, -24(%rsp)
    movss   (%rsi), %xmm2
    mulss   %xmm4, %xmm0
    mulss   %xmm2, %xmm1
    mulss   %xmm3, %xmm2
    subss   %xmm5, %xmm1
    subss   %xmm2, %xmm0
    movss   %xmm1, -20(%rsp)
    movss   %xmm0, -16(%rsp)
    movq    -24(%rsp), %xmm0
    movd    -16(%rsp), %xmm1
    ret
```

So the assembly is identical. But I agree that it would be more practical to store as an static array (that is, a `float m_data[3]`) because I can have the best of both worlds: a single parameter to pass when I need to, and a high-level, idiomatic `x`, `y`, `z` via getters. In that sense, I believe I would implement such class in a manner similar to:

```
class MyPoint3S {
 public:
  MyPoint3S(float x, float y, float z)
      : m_data{x, y, z} { }

  // the following getters will be inlined
  float x() const {
    return m_data[0];
  }

  float y() const {
    return m_data[1];
  }

  float z() const {
    return m_data[2];
  }

  // in case you want to use the pointer --- some would advice against
  // offering a hook to a private member.
  float* data() {
    return m_data;
  }

 private:
  float m_data[3];
};
```

And use it like:

```
MyPoint3S p(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
std::cout<<"p = "<<p.x()<<", "<<p.y()<<", "<<p.z()<<std::endl;
```

to obtain:

```
p = 1, 2, 3
```

Or call OpenGL functions in whatever way you prefer:

```
glVertex3fv(p.data());
```

or

```
glVertex3f(p.x(), p.y(), p.z());
```

Comment: Very good answer.
Thank you for researching this case translating to assembler, I find it so interesting.
I think your proposition is reasonable, also knowing glVertexv* is usually more efficient as I have posted bellow, and it's easier than using unions.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a [union](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/)? Use a struct and now you can access them both ways. Performance-wise it shouldn't make any difference with a decent compiler.

```
struct Point3F {
union {
  float data[3];
  struct {float x, float y, float z};
}
};

Point3F a;
a.x = 21;
a.data[1] == 42;
assert(a.data[0] == 21); // Same data
assert(a.y == 42); // Same data
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer by myself. Extracted from the red-book of openGL ([It can be read here](http://www.esiee.fr/~perrotol/TheRedBook-1.0/chapter02.html)):

> On some machines, the vector form of glVertex*() is more efficient,
>   since only a single parameter needs to be passed to the graphics
>   subsystem, and special hardware might be able to send a whole series
>   of coordinates in a single batch. If your machine is like this, it's
>   to your advantage to arrange your data so that the vertex coordinates
>   are packed sequentially in memory.

But I'm still wondering which is better, for example, for triangle class: one array of points or each individual point one by one. The same question can be extended to more complex types.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the first need more run-time memory and the other need more
>   cpu usage.

Both classes have the *exact* same storage size. If your compiler says `float`s are 4 bytes, then you have 12 bytes total for your whole class. The second example packs them together as a single block of memory, where the first example treats them as individual 4 byte chunks.

As far as efficiency, these are all constant time access. It does not matter.

I think you should use the first one. `point.x` is more descriptive than `point.coord[0]`.